# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip, kivy, ubuntu-18.04, kivy-language

This is the error I am getting while installing kivy-deps.angle

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle-dev (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle-dev

Can anybody please help

Answer (score 0):

The current version kivy-deps.angle-dev 0.2.0 [provides wheels](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.angle-dev/0.2.0/#files) for Python 3.6-3.8 for w32 and w64 only. No other wheels and no source code at PyPI.

If you need kivy-deps.angle-dev for a different Python or a different OS you have to compile from sources. If there is something to compile — I downloaded a wheel and didn't find any code inside it.