# I have an error when i put my django project on Heroku: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, django, heroku, server, pip

i don't want this package in my project, how can i skip him? Or what can i make?

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Processing /D:/Python/mymodules/dist/vsearch-1.0.tar.gz
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/D:/Python/mymodules/dist/vsearch-1.0.tar.gz'
```

Comment: Remove this package from your requirements.txt

Comment: i have another problem... what can i make with this?  remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2 (from versions: none)

remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2

Comment: It means that either this package : `kivy-deps.angle==0.3.2` does not exist or the pip is not able to find it

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209953/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-kivy-deps-angle

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Divyessh, he answered my question.

So, if you have a problem like my, you can remove the package that you don't need from your requirements.txt.

After that you can change the requirement to `UTF-8`, it will help you if you have a problem like `??0/0?` or something like this.

```
pip freeze | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 requirements.txt
```